# How to filter only first row in sets of data on Excel 2016

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I have sets of data like this on Excel 2016
[image]

Can I filter only first row by these sets of time? e.g. I want to select only first row of February 1st on 12AM and February 1st on 6AM.

Thank you for your help and attention.

Comment: I imagine that with a combination of a unique formula and an array of vlookup functions this could be achieved. The only thing is that the output would have to be inserted in a different range, rather than filtering the existing data. Could you specify what would be an acceptable solution to your question?

Ps. It would be preferable if you inserted the data as a table rather than inserting a screenshot in order to create a relevant solution.

Comment: To get unique value one would need one formula not multiple: `=INDEX(A$2:A$9,MATCH(0,COUNTIF(I$1:I1,$A$2:$A$9),0),)` drag right and down, and since `Excel 2016` would need to hit `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER` to bypass `CSE` just wrap the match within `INDEX()` .

Comment: @IBas Sorry if I inserted only the screenshot because I don't know how to create table in Stackoverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per screenshot of my answer use the following formula to <kbd>K2</kbd> cell.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$9,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($K$1:K1,$A$2:$A$9),0,0),0)),"")
```

Then use the following formula to <kbd>L2</kbd> cell.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$H$9,MATCH($K2,$A$2:$A$9,0),COLUMN(A$1)),"")
```

Drag the formula as per your need.

[image]

Comment: Wow thank you for your answer, I've tried it and it works !!